# cadaddadadaddddaddddddr - linked list accessing

Tags: code-golf, array, subsequence, lisp, ragged-list

Create a function (or closest equivalent, or full program) that takes an list of some datatype (your choice) that may be nested and a string (in either order), and generalizes the lisp c[ad]+r functions.

> <sub>Functions are provided which perform compositions of up to four car and cdr operations.</sub> Their names consist of a C, followed by <s>two, three, or four</s><sup>any positive number</sup> occurrences of A or D, and finally an R. The series of A's and D's in each function's name is chosen to identify the series of `car` and `cdr` operations that is performed by the function. The order in which the A's and D's appear is the inverse of the order in which the corresponding operations are performed.

[(source: common lisp hyperspec)](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm)

The `car` and `cdr` operations will return the first element and all the other elements, respectively, for the purposes of this challenge. The string will hold the operation you should perform.

### Examples:

```
   Array    ,  Accessor  =>  Result
===================================
     [0,1,2],      'cdr' => [1,2]
 [0,[1,2],3],     'cadr' => [1,2]
 [[[[[0]]]]],   'caaaar' => [0]
          [],      'cdr' => do not need to handle (no cdr)
          [],      'car' => do not need to handle (no car)
    anything, 'cr'/'asd' => do not need to handle (invalid command)
         [0],      'car' => 0
         [0],      'cdr' => []
```

### Reference Implementation

```js
{

  const inp = document.getElementById("inp");
  const out = document.getElementById("out");
  inp.onchange = () => {
    const data = JSON.parse(inp.value);
    var list = data.list;
    data.cmd.match(/^c([ad]+)r$/)[1]
      .split("").reverse().forEach(letter =>
        list = letter === "a" ? list[0] : list.slice(1));
    out.value = JSON.stringify(list);
  };
  inp.onchange();

}
```

```html
<textarea id="inp" rows="2" cols="50">
{ "cmd": "cadadr",
  "list": [0,[1,[2,3],4],5] }
</textarea>
<br>
<textarea readonly id="out" rows="1" cols="50">
waiting, there seems to be a problem
</textarea>
```

*This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest solution in bytes per language wins.*

Comment: [Sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20917/90614)

Comment: Would `(cadr [0,[1,2],3])` not give `[1,2]` since `(cdr [0,[1,2],3])` is `[[1,2],3]` and then `(car [[1,2],3])` is `[1,2]`?

Comment: So `cadr` would be `cdr` then `car`, or `car` then `cdr`?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms _"The order in which the A's and D's appear is the inverse of the order in which the corresponding operations are performed."_ so `(cadr x)` is `(car (cdr x))`

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes, that's correct. Fixing.

Comment: Here is something related [in real life](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/gencadr.txr). Code which generates the cadr functions in C, to a depth of 5, from `caar` to `cdddddr`. Generated code [here](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/cadr.c) and [here](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/share/txr/stdlib/cadr.tl).

Comment: @Kaz Right, I actually got the idea looking at lisp implementation code and wondering if it could be automated (hopefully it was automated when it was created, otherwise I feel sorry for their fingers ;).

Comment: Regarding your fourth and fifth examples, I believe that in most LISP implementations, both `(CAR ())`  and `(CDR ())` will return `nil` or `()`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That's true for Common lisp and not for scheme, so I just chose the one that made sense. It's also easier for most languages.

Comment: as a noob, where can i read about this to fully understand it

Comment: @thejonymyster If you're asking about linked lists, you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list . `car` returns the first element of a linked list and `cdr` returns the rest.

Comment: @Wezl-acautionarytale thank you, now that you say it, i can see it written in the challenge. I was kind of glazing over it. Personally, I'd recommend putting the definition of `car` and `cdr` before the sourced quote which refers to them

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 48 bytes

```javascript
a=>f=b=>b[2]?b[[x,...r]=f(b.slice(1)),1]<f?x:r:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDdasQgEIXv8xRzUVDBSrK9KduafRArxLhmcXFj0DQEln32NK4JhdJz48/5Zg4zVzWpqIMdxtfpfdG@jyNE775H63vgi@J1x1tet@IgT60QM2WMBck73LLorDa4IoRW8rM7zcdwVFsHraKJwKEpIEmUtKIHSZ8PQPocEPAaRPoskvu80beNQFr9IZJKmUSzv2ojSpkzcs5vxuaX/7t7f1k0bAz2hgmLg7MjRl89IuymBuxsbxKTzt3kNSLko@h8AJwnFSpcIgUzD0aP5izBd3l6Avc1eocoRLnuw0zK4Ua83FPVQzZrr8x4Z5jzF7yvHiuCY4p6LD8)

*-2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld!*

Comment: I'm out of votes for the day, remind me to upvote this later :p

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDdasQgEIXv8xRzUVDBSrK9KduafRArxLhmcXFj0DQEln32NK4JhdJz48/5Zg4zVzWpqIMdxtfpfdG@jyNE775H63vgi@J1x1tet@IgT60QM2WMBck73LLorDa4IoRW8rM7zcdwVFsHraKJwKEpIEmUtKIHSZ8PQPocEPAaRPoskvu80beNQFr9IZJKmUSzv2ojSpkzcs5vxuaX/7t7f1k0bAz2hgmLg7MjRl89IuymBuxsbxKTzt3kNSLko@h8AJwnFSpcIgUzD0aP5izBd3l6Avc1eocoRLnuw0zK4Ua83FPVQzZrr8x4Z5jzF7yvHiuCY4p6LD8)

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>68</s> <s>66</s> 54 bytes

```python
lambda r,s:eval(s[:0:-1].translate(["[1:]","[0]"]*51))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBCsIwEEX3nkJmlcgoicVNoCeZzmK0LQoxliQIPX00WUnxLd/j/2XN91foytwPxcvzOso@YnLTW7xK5Iw7Wj7lKCF5yZMiIOsYEMgw8OFitS5LfISsZkUGLZ4Z4TZG0Hr346mFrjbZxIrhSo1fNtum/7h2Uz4)

Alt, similar idea (which works in Python 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```python
lambda l,c:eval(l+''.join("[[10:]]"[x<'d'::2]for x in c[-2:0:-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcyxDsIgFIXh3acgLECkBuhG6pMgA4JEDEJDGlOfHgsupvEf75dz5/dyz2ms/nyp0TyvzoBIrby9TMTxiNDpkUPCUCnOpNZQrRNySEqhfS5gBSEBqwYhmRy4JqTOJaQF@23AKKdCQwqtK5CQw6@oRnTsavbcYrrVeWu//8Lfa39WPw)

Both create an eval string which just appends the desired sequence of subscripts/slices directly to the list, with the first one using the added trick of keeping the "r" as the list name. The first one takes an actual list as input and the second takes a string representation of a list.

Credit to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for pointing me at `translate()` and the idea of using `r` as the list name for -12 bytes!

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
Oị⁾ḢḊḊṖUv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4e7uR437Hu5Y9HBHFwjtnBZa9v/wcqWjkx7unPGoaU3k///qySlF6joK6smJMBoIoCwIBRT/H22gY6hjFKujAGREg1nGIA4IGMSCAEgGQgAA)

-2 bytes thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)!

Takes the accessor on the left and the array on the right

```
Oị⁾ḢḊḊṖUv - Main link. Accessor A on left, Array L on right
O         - Convert A to ordinals. Note that 'a' is odd and 'd' is even
 ị⁾ḢḊ     - Index into "ḢḊ". Odd characters yield "Ḣ" and even "Ḋ"
     ḊṖ   - Remove first and last values from A
       U  - Reverse
        v - Evaluate as Jelly code, with L as the argument
```

`Ḣ` is the *head* command, which returns the first element of a list. `Ḋ` is the *dequeue* command, which removes the first element of a list. The code executed by `v` is just a series of `Ḣ` and `Ḋ` atoms, which perform one after another.

Comment: I'm just gonna assume this aHdDyDPUvs the input, in which case this is self-explanatory.

Comment: @Wezl Yeah, it's a well know Jelly program, to `aHdDyDPUv` the input :) Explanation added

Comment: [-2 by cutting out `y`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4e7uR437Hu5Y9HBHFwjtnBZa9v/wcqWjkx7unPGoaU3k///qySlF6joK6smJMBoIoCwIBRT/H22gY6hjFKujAGREg1nGIA4IGMSCAEgGQgAA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Very nice, thanks!

Comment: Stole the insight from Jonathan Allan outgolfing me 

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```
[ rest reverse rest [ 97 = [ first ] [ rest ] if ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvBCsIwEETvfsXQD5BaD6LiWbx4EU8lhxC3WNQ2bqIgod8e1zYBd2B23rDbaON7jufT4bjf4Ebc0R2WyfuP5bbzcPR8UWfIYTsLCCixQIVhTCHl5chZpVDWRKmT/8JcuMBvCqNzzCzz36RWqulriDWYnBd7EzuaoMZ6hZ2spmVBhXSk0DZipM0VKlYPbTGPXw)

*-4 bytes thanks to @Neil!*

### Explanation:

This is a quotation (anonymous function) that takes two sequences from the data stack and leaves one sequence on the data stack. In Factor, strings are just sequences of unicode code points and can be manipulated like any other sequence.

- Given input `{ 0 { 1 2 } 3 } "cadr"`...
- `rest` take everything but the first element of a sequence `{ 0 { 1 2 } 3 } "adr"`
- `reverse` reverse a sequence `{ 0 { 1 2 } 3 } "rda"`
- `rest` take everything but the first element of a sequence `{ 0 { 1 2 } 3 } "da"`
- `[ ... ] each` for each element in the sequence...
- At the beginning of the first iteration, the data stack looks like this: `{ 0 { 1 2 } 3 } 100`
- `97` push `97` on the data stack `{ 0 { 1 2 } 3 } 100 97`
- `=` test top two objects on the data stack for equality `{ 0 { 1 2 } 3 } f`
- `[ first ] [ rest ] if` run first quotation if TOS is `t`, otherwise run the second `{ { 1 2 } 3 }`
- Now the next iteration of `each` will kick in and put the next command on the data stack `{ { 1 2 } 3 } 97`
- Etc.

Comment: `but-last reverse` can be `reverse rest` to save four bytes.

Comment: @Neil Clever, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 86 bytes

```lisp
(λ(a c)(foldr(λ(c a)(case c[(#\a)(car a)][(#\d)(cdr a)][else a]))a(string->list c)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBDsIwDATvfYXVHrAPfKEfgR5MnFRRoyAl@R1/4EvBDhIVe5vR7hZ2h299SZx3KAMmFB9i9hA6vl/I4AjDM0kxcsCEjqsHd8PlPqCo24xESb7kk1Z4I2KsrcS8X9cUa9Mvok4TBrjo80MZZt3MP4XDiWk@vYXJYl5zLob5R9v1Dw)

-3 bytes thanks to Wezl
-73 bytes thanks to ASCII-only
-8 bytes thanks to MLavrentyev

Input in the format `(f <data> <string>)`

Of course there has to be a lisp/scheme/racket/whatever answer :P

This is probably pretty bad because it's my first time golfing in Racket. I just know what I was taught in my basic first-year CS courses :P

Comment: So which one function do you use, and what's the argument order?

Comment: @Wezl `f`, and the data comes first, then the string

Comment: You can remove the newline, `string=?` can become `equal?` or maybe `eqv?`, I'll see if there are generic substitutes for `string-length` and `substring`. If not, some bytes may be saved by taking a list instead of a string or converting the string to a list.

Comment: @Wezl Oh I didn't realize `equal?` would work here, thanks. Also forgot about the newline

Comment: understandable, let's work on removing every shred of good style and readability. :)

Comment: [157](https://tio.run/##dU3NDoIwDL77FM28tAcSpnd5EMKhjjGJy4xjPP/sQBPxp4c2/X4jm6tNee85OIjrg70dxmDRgQEmNLfQt2jvM/tGKUPctTilOAZ3apQRAA1HdDjN5xUWmyYm6lqNpv9NEb1aBmCQjA8RVs@Oytvg0kUkmooziwH9OCWoQcOBQEmFot0bvN6FPBaet4J/u6YyRS@zjVzQb6jk5gc)

Comment: [148](https://tio.run/##dY3BDoIwDIbvPkUDl/ZgAnqXB0EOzTYW4jLjgOef7YgJaOyhzf//X9vE5uGWXAeOHtIm0Lpxig49GGBC84y2x7iG0IEhHnp0rw4NJ1H1XQFO6NFYNZjoC7Ck0RFod3Ig@jwcgcWSbF7SFP35FqZ52XayhFhkAy1cCCrZr@i0s7dZwqvmfAT@9Ya0lJc6nizur6V38xs)

Comment: went out to walk the dog, [110](https://tio.run/##dc3BDsIgDAbg@56i2S7lYLLpXR9Ed6hQFiKyCGSvj8BiDDH2AOFr@@NJPjimwZJbwNdHh4q1cQw6oaXnXRESSIF6tcp@RAIJlKtTV@TXBSQMtwLks89fU9nUbhPQLASh5419YAzRG7ccztaEmONzJdGhBqwwwgRHAX3e7hve79o8lT61A//OsXxQ53O1kVV/qeSmNw)

Comment: [94](https://tio.run/##dYy7DsMgDEX3fIWVLPZQKWn3/kibweURoVIqAf9PDFEHFNUD6Bxf38jqbXKZPIcNYoMBtbEuGLAFPX9empFBEdqv1/FnFDCh4mRAPXB6Noji1kpaSB9kvER4JWJMObqwXe7epSx9RIUGtICNZ1jgSjDK3djp42/LW91zH/j3zlSn5mX6ymbPqvaWHQ)

Comment: so, yes, *some* bytes can be saved by converting the string to a list. not sure if it's acceptable to take a list instead of a string; if it's valid the jq answer can avoid the split too. also might want to use `'(a b c)` instead of `(list a b c)` for readability.

Comment: @ASCII-only lol at this point this may as well be a new answer xD do you want to post yours

Comment: not really tbh im not a racket person. if i could be bothered i could post a common lisp one maybe.

Comment: @ASCII-only okay, fair enough. well thanks for the golfs!

Comment: @HyperNeutrino you can also replace `lambda` with a `λ`. Both more readable and shorter.

Comment: @MLavrentyev that would've been nice to know when i was doing lambda calculus for my cs class in racket, lol. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```python
lambda l,c,a=lambda x:x[0],d=lambda x:x[1:]:eval("(".join(d(c))[:-1]+l+")"*(len(c)-2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxNDoIwEAXgvacws5qRwfCza8JJahe1hYiphRBC8PSVVheE@HbvfZkZ3/Nj8HXomltw@nW3@uzYsG5@ZRWrLBTbfS@FEu2iHQLC9Tn0Hi0aIinyUmUuA4ILutZvW14RhXHq/Ywdgiy45EoBg7ETEJ32IiNxnVQfOaZQMYm3HO@/8HdNz8IH)

-1 byte thanks to @Stephen

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcxNDoIwEAXgvacws5qRwfCza8JJahe1hYiphRBC8PSVVheE@HbvfZkZ3/Nj8HXomltw@nW3@uzYsG5@ZRWrLBTbfS@FEu2iHQLC9Tn0Hi0aIinyUmUuA4ILutZvW14RhXHq/Ywdgiy45EoBg7ETEJ32IiNxnVQfOaZQMYm3HO@/8HdNz8IH "Python 3 – Try It Online") by re-using your `d` lambda

Comment: @Stephen That's clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Scala, 60 bytes

```scala
_.tail.init.:\(_){case(x,m:Seq[_])=>if(x<98)m(0)else m.tail}
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RMkauukDRLm5rS3bWBvb3w)

I hate nested lists. Because of them, we need a pattern matching function (or casts, which are longer).

```scala
_                            //The command ("caadddaddaar")
  .tail                      //Drop the 'c'
  .init                      //Drop the 'r'
.:\                          //Fold right the "aadddada"
  (_)                        //Starting with the inputted list
  {                          //Pattern matching function literal
    case (x, m: Seq[_]) =>   //The command is x, the list is m (must be a Seq)
    if (x < 98) m(0)         //If the command is 'a', return the first element
    else m.tail              //Else, drop the first element
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 35 bytes

```
4 :0
".'y',~(}.}:x)rplc;:'a{.d}.'
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpNCgMhDIbhvacI3UTBSvqzip3DiI6UUmhx1VLs1TMyarJ7v@chkhe@ApM6OPyi/evqKn9MeT@jZww/l6pDZWSN9xfo2wnOBo4MGEMqCBk0@db8xaguLNME7XZieT51RAOMdVTEntPMsgE)

<sup>Note: -3 off TIO count for `f=:`</sup>

- Drop the first and last element from the `c[ad]+r` directive with `}.}:x`, leaving us with a string of `a`s and `d`s.
- Replace every `a` with `{.` and every `d` with `}.`, J's version of car and cdr: `rplc;:'a{.d}.'`
- Append the nested array we want to evaluate `'y',~`.
- And evaluate it `".`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (V8), <s>77</s> 72 bytes

```js
c=>d=>[...c.slice(1)].reverse(d=[d]).map(n=>d=n=="d"?d.slice(1):d[0])&&d
```

Turns out the boring solution wins

## JavaScript (V8), <s>91</s> <s>90</s> <s>87</s> 84 bytes

```js
c=>d=>[...c.slice(1)].map(n=>x=>n=="d"?x.slice(1):x[0]).reduceRight((a,f)=>f(a),[d])
```

Can't add a TIO link on school WiFi :/

**Explanation:**

This is a cool approach, using functional stuff. It `slice`s the command name to remove the `c`, splits it into characters, then maps them to functions:

- `d` becomes `x=>x.slice(1)`
- `a` and `r` become `x=>x[0]`

My current approach actually returns one function, which can still access the `n` variable, which saves three bytes. I don't really know how to explain it but it works :p

It then uses `reduceRight` to apply those functions in reverse order, on `[d]`. This saves a byte over my old approach, which also sliced off the `r`.

Comment: How do you post solutions from your school? I am curious to know

Comment: @Wasif The same way I would at home, minus TIO

Comment: no, when do you get time there

Comment: For school wifi, try using a VPN.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
.v+PtXQ"da""th"\E
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=.v%2BPtXQ%22da%22%22th%22%5CE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22cdr%22%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%22cadr%22%0A%5B0%2C%5B1%2C2%5D%2C3%5D%0A%22caaaar%22%0A%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B0%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%0A%22car%22%0A%5B0%5D%0A%22cdr%22%0A%5B%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Uses pretty much the same approach as [ChartZ Belatedly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/chartz-belatedly)['s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221348/78186).

---

As an aside, this answer could shed 3/4 bytes if Pyth had an 'evaluate with argument' builtin, and an additional 1/2 if it had Jelly's 'transliterate' (Pyth builtins can be one or two bytes). This would put it at 11/12/13 bytes, which *at best* ties the 11 bytes Jelly takes. This is especially impressive since Jelly has to reverse the accessor, while Pyth doesn't (Pyth uses reverse Polish notation).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 69 bytes

Takes an object with keys `"c"` for the accessor and `"l"` for the list.

```perl
reduce((.c/"")[1:-1]|reverse[])as$c(.l;if$c=="d"then.[1:]else.[0]end)
```

### Explanation

```perl
reduce        $0               as$c($1;             $2              )
  # the accumulator starts at $1. For each $0 (stored as the variable $c),
  # it becomes the result of $2 applied to it.
      ((.c/"")[1:-1]|reverse[])
  # the command (.c), split (/""), with the ends snapped ([1:-1])
  # reversed (reverse), every value inside this array  ([])
                                    .l;if$c=="d"then.[1:]else.[0]end
  # starting with the list (.l), if the character is "d" then the list
  # becomes its tail (.[1:]), otherwise its head (.[0]).
```

[Jq play it!](https://jqplay.org/s/uq_vWjur6j)

[Run test cases](https://jqplay.org/s/3Bs9t95CxM)

Comment: You might want to make the explanation a separate block.

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Eh, I kind of liked how it was, plus it probably took shorter to load.

Comment: Hehe funny byte number. Nice.

Comment: it probably took like 1ms shorter to load so wouldn't have been noticeable

Comment: `$c=="d"` -> `$c>"a"`

Comment: @ASCII-only I'll edit it if a substantial amount of bytes are saved. Otherwise, it's staying at `69` ;).

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
VÔkric)¬£=X¥'a?UÎ:UÅ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=VtRrcmljKayjPVilJ2E/Vc46VcU&input=WzAsWzEsMl0sM10gICAgCiJjYWRyIgo)

- saved 2 thanks to @Shaggy

```
    1st input U = data
    2nd input V = command
    
    VÔk"cr" - reverse and remove 'cr'
    £ ... Ã - pass each remaining letters to :
    =         - reassign 1st input(U)
    X¥'a?UÎ   - 1st item if 'a'
    :UÅÃ      - else the rest
    -h flag to output result
```

Comment: [20 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=VtRrcmljKayjPVilJ2E/Vc46VcU&input=WzAsWzEsMl0sM10gICAgCiJjYWRyIgo)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç≈≡ø*fáì☺○
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80f7f0002a66a08d0109&i=%5B0,1,2%5D,+%22cdr%22%0A%5B0,%5B1,2%5D,3%5D,+%22cadr%22%0A%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B0%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D,+%22caaaar%22%0A%5B%5D,+%22cdr%22%0A%5B%5D,+%22car%22%0Aanything,+%22cr%22%2F%22asd%22%0A%5B0%5D,+%22car%22%0A%5B0%5D,+%22cdr%22&m=2)

Returns a string of codepoints if array, and number if it's a number. The code can be verified here: [Try it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%22ahdD%22%7CtrDNdlcc%7C4%7B%7Cu%7Da%3F&i=%5B0,1,2%5D,+%22cdr%22%0A%5B0,%5B1,2%5D,3%5D,+%22cadr%22%0A%5B%5B%5B%5B%5B0%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D,+%22caaaar%22%0A%5B%5D,+%22cdr%22%0A%5B%5D,+%22car%22%0Aanything,+%22cr%22%2F%22asd%22%0A%5B0%5D,+%22car%22%0A%5B0%5D,+%22cdr%22&m=2)

### Explanation

```
"ahdD"|trDl
"ahdD"|t    translate 'a' to 'h' and 'd'  to 'D'
        r   reverse
         D  delete first element
          l eval

checking code:
cc|4{|u}a?
cc         dup twice
  |4     ? if it's an array:
    {|u}   convert to JSON
        a  otherwise leave as is
```

Comment: What does the `|` before the `t` do? **EDIT**: Oh, looks like it forms a "ligature" with `t` to make a new command.

Comment: yep `|` is a prefix for a lot of commands

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｆ⮌η≡ιa≔§θ⁰θd≔ΦθλθcＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcq9CsIwEADg3ae4LXcQoeqmUxEKbuIaMhxJNIHQkh@qID57rCCI8/cZz9lMHFu7Thnw4maXi0NPBOUeqvGAgeC5MlwcCBZ76EsJtxH7ehqte2CS0JGERIfvsb8zhFhd/pT4V8xSzjmMFY9cKiZa5NWaUp1UG7nVcqelMGyz0G09xzc) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs using Charcoal's default format, which is each array element on its own line and each subarray double-spaced from the next (+1 byte to output in Python `str` format). Explanation:

```
Ｆ⮌η≡ι
```

Loop over the command characters in reverse order and switch on them.

```
a≔§θ⁰θ
```

For `a` replace the input with its first element.

```
d≔Φθλθ
```

For `d` filter the first element from the input.

```
cＩθ
```

For `c` print the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 73 bytes

```
+`(a|(d))r.(((\[)|(?<-5>])|\d|(?(5),))+),?(?(2)(?<3>.*)|.*)
r$#2$*[$3
cr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDsMgDEV3rlEG/8SNUlC2KjmIg1QEHbp0sDpyd2L6JMvv21/fv8839z6/KDeqgC5EdAoaHc/7tie0s5rTBgZm8GEeYM@4LxOajVN/C34SH11R13upKis/OCRX8t9lBI4jGyqDNQ3sYgVbo5cu) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
+`
```

Repeat until a match cannot be made.

```
(a|(d))r.(((\[)|(?<-5>])|\d|(?(5),))+),?(?(2)(?<3>.*)|.*)
```

Match either an `a` or `d` (remembering which), then an implied `[`, then a sequence of `[`s, `]`s, `,`s and digits, except no more `]`s than `[`s and only matching `,`s between `[`s and `]`s, then an optional `,`, then if it was a `d` that matched then replace the match of the first term with the tail of the list otherwise just delete the tail.

```
r$#2$*[$3
```

Keep the `r`, re-insert the `[` if the `d` was matched, and insert the first term or tail as matched above.

```
cr
```

Finally delete the remaining `cr`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 100 bytes

```lua
load[[t,c=...c:reverse():gsub('[ad]',load"if...=='a'then t=t[1]else table.remove(t,1)end")return t]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVCxboMwEJ3hK04sxpKDknaLROeO3TqgDA4cqVXHIGNAVZRvT88GQhJLlux37969e7qXN92UUkMNOb1kVRROlHmWZeXe4oC2w5TvT11/TFkhqwMTnpSomhh5ziRzP2jA5a7YHVB3CE4eNWYWz82AqRM7jqZKuEXXW@IdDrfNBj5Rt2ih7k3pVGOgbiy0VhmnzAksdr12XTzbWjgVYvvlOSlNEGBw1DyOVB1ekOdglIZgZgLA2R6BhgeS@2vRN3LPZMEjC@w4ilSTjVY5TNmFkWQ0D1a2c7MMgd7irxhAGVCtpNqkVjVUCy4aN7cED6umAMYhJLMo1tL/grMoWtcaxFTxFqbiKnL1xrzII@oNxNGyYdg6zA5JpjxM8DemxL@tbCny11DHKczyXJHSS8KLmcdVEvYITG1rPYHNB7AnpXodwO9mxvRypViISa@tgJ2ANw@Ulb1jlxl8DwW5VPzZXv0JMJ2lZQKefr7p9g8)

Function that accepts a nested table structure and a string. I sure would be impressed to see this golfed further. Please note that original table structure *will* be modified when using `d` command, so don't pass it there if it have value to you (or, better yet, never use this code outside of TIO sandbox).

TIO link also includes a test suite.

Answer (score 2):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), <s>106</s> 104 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(a c)(reduce(lambda(a c)(if(eq c #\a)(car a)(if(eq c #\d)(cdr a)a)))(reverse c):initial-value a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xDsIwDER3vsIKQtgDP8DGf7C4iSNFSgtN0o799eBkgonceL7nOxtDflfMUlbwFSPPk2NksIRJ3GblxwoeZQUL5ycTWk7A355TzzWPiRq@S8qi2D0soQSOt53jJnqnSif0rzRzgQLmeBwXA@i3xXKM4OGqbZOCYPSfof9h7GnXAB4hmtpI6oRqpKVnR4N9Rf0A)

Direct port of the racket answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 17 bytes

```
£ḢṪṘƛ\a=[&h|&Ḣ];¥
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%A3%E1%B8%A2%E1%B9%AA%E1%B9%98%C6%9B%5Ca%3D%5B%26h%7C%26%E1%B8%A2%5D%3B%C2%A5&inputs=%5B%5B1%2C%5B3%2C5%2C8%5D%2C5%5D%2C2%2C3%5D%0Acaddadar&header=&footer=)

A mess :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>80</s> <s>79</s> 75 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,x:eval(['%s[1:]','%s[0]','x#%s','%s'][ord(s[0])%4]%'f(s[1:],x)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvBCsIwDIbvPoVMShvIoXMeZLAnCT1Ua1GYW2mH1Kevpigy/0vyf18Snst1nrpjiKX4YbT3k7PbhLm/POyoSIpEbW8k8qJ55p1ItUpDc3SKMYiDEdKreosZJJQQb9OivGrOLjZIGlvcG4DNj9uPIDbY/cl3WHO04ax1fV0z92XlBQ)

By sheer luck, `ord(s[0])%4` is able to distinguish between `a`, `c`, `d`, `r`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 71 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.875 bytes

```
ḢṪṘ(₍ḢhnAi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4bii4bmq4bmYKOKCjeG4omhuQWkiLCIiLCJjYWFhYXJcbltbW1tbMF1dXV1dIl0=)

### Explained

```
ḢṪṘ(₍ḢhnAi
ḢṪ         # Remove the c and r from the input
  Ṙ        # and reverse it
   (       # for each char
    ₍Ḣh    #   [top_of_stack[1:], top_of_stack[0]]
         i #   indexed by
       nA  #   is char a vowel?
```