# Reverse cadaddadadaddddaddddddr

Tags: code-golf, array, lisp

The Lisp language has a family of functions `car`, `cdr`, `cadr`, etc for accessing arrays. For each one, an `a` defines taking the first item of an array, and a `d` defines taking the rest.

For example, running `cadr` on `[[1,3,4],5,7]` will return `[3,4]` as the `a` gets the first item (`[1,3,4]`) and the `d` removes the first item.

We've already had a [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221344/cadaddadadaddddaddddddr-linked-list-accessing) regarding running a `cadaddadadaddddaddddddr` on a list, but what about the reverse?

Your challenge is to, given a string of the type above (starting with a `c`, ending with a `r`, with only `ad` in the middle), and a single value, create an array such that running the string as a `cadaddadadaddddaddddddr` on the array returns said value.

For example, given the input `cadar, 1` a possible output could be `[[0,[1]]]` since running `cadar` on that gives 1.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

## Testcases

These are possible outputs, all that matters is that your program  returns an array which works for the condition.

```
car, 3 => [3]
cdddar, 5 => [0,0,0,5]
cadadadadar, 4 => [[0,[0,[0,[0,[4]]]]]]
caaaaaaaaar, 2 => [[[[[[[[[[2]]]]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Is the value we're given always a number? Can our array have values of other types? This can matter for using a constant value for the padding and guaranteeing it's different from the specified value.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the value cannot be a list, so the string necessarily ends in `ar`?

Comment: @att The value may be anything your language supports.

Comment: @xnor The value could be anything your language supports. The other values don't havve to  be different from the specified one, all that matters is that running the caddr on the produced list returns the correct result.

Comment: I still don't understand how this is supposed to work when it ends in `dr`.  This could be much better explained, but should really have at the minimum a test case.

Comment: Still unclear if we must support `c....dr` - and that we, therefore need to be able to take both integers and lists/arrays as the value input. (Perhaps allowing value to always be a list if the language is strongly typed?)

Comment: I think the 3rd case may give [[0,[0,[0,[0,4]]]]]  , the first element of the tail of [0,4] is 4 e.g. "cdar" of [0,4] or am I missing something ?

Comment: Do we read the string of `a`s and `d`s left-to-right or the other way? The test cases assume the former, but the linked question and [Lisp itself](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm) the latter.

Comment: I'm going to be closing this until this is all sorted out to prevent further answers and thus reduce the cleanup that will be required.

Comment: Op's note: I've made a lot of mistakes while drafting this  question, and I don't think it's salvageable.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,*l:s[3:]and f(s[1:],l,*l)or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NjsIwDITvfQorJ0BF2vJziZQDD8Gp6sE4qRph3KppF@3Td50CEsll/M2MPfxNXS@HZWkd4@PmEVK5Y5vqo21QPLSbVFe2KVnpth@Bl2cXOUBlC02KizLM02ZbAIPL4VJUD2OUCbiAVhsEUSAv2VeNliC2QM4ZNHlYa1z/NKoDvy3/benx1Uthha/V5ip36Z8C1OGINIXRlECfw@ZCFFIKHn6R5wAxWbV5MYQ5dywMee9XfVaN/v0zOGXweRkc/gE)

Doesn't bother telling car from cdr. Instead, makes a big nested tuple where every path ends at the right value, assuming it has the right length and ends in `a`. For example,

```python
f("cdddar", 5) = ((((5,), 5), (5,), 5), ((5,), 5), (5,), 5)
```

is the same as `f("caaaar", 5)` or `f("cdadar", 5)`. So, only the length of the input string matters.

This is done by repeating the transformation `l -> (l,*l)`, which puts `l` as both the car and cdr of the new tuple. This happens once for each character in `s` except the first three, starting from a singleton of the input value.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
RA"¸  Ć"‡.V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/yFHp0A4FhSNtSo8aFuqF/bflUuIKSy3KTMtMTizJzM@zUlDS4Tq089CKQ8sUyhQq7ZUUdO0UlOwVKpUSU5SULuw9tAyi0bb2f3JiChQWcZkAAA)

```python
R             # reverse the input
 A            # push the lower case alphabet
  "¸  Ć"‡     # transliterate, replace:
              #  - "a" with "¸" (wrap)
              #  - "c" with " " (noop)
              #  - "d" with "Ć" (enclose, append the first value)
         .V   # evaluate as 05AB1E code, the leading r reverses the empty stack
```

---

Porting [xnor's construction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233416/64121) comes in at 5 bytes:

```
g<GDš
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVMArP9vc2FiaWX//2c8R0TFof9dPQoiClZlcmlmaWNhdGlvbjogIiwKwrnCqMKmIHYgeT8iIC0@ICI/IHkiYWQiItC9wqYi4oChLlY9ff9jZGRkYXIKNQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
(nH₂[w|⁰J
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B8%A2%28nH%E2%82%82%5Bw%7CJ&inputs=car%0A2&header=&footer=)

Wow, using hexadecimal conversion actually helped save a byte. Exits with an error, but outputs the required list wrapped in a list.

### Explained

```py
(nH₂[w|⁰J
(          # for each character `n` in the remnants:
 nH        #     convert to hexadecimal
   ₂       #     is that divisible by 2?
    [      #     if so:
     w     #         wrap the TOS in a list ([TOS])
      |    #     else:
       ⁰J  #         join the TOS and the next input
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>47</sup> 41 bytes

```
4 :0
".'y',~(}.}:x)rplc a`,:`d,<'(,{.)'
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNDoIwEIX3PcWLm6EJNgZxU@zGA3gBYgKhrWIMmEKMBvHqCCj@zGzmfZP3HbvOKhlCLthM0I38h9eKVl65O58ypIkvE@2vyfMbwYnxbrsRcOZiXGWgc2eyOi8L2NKhNlWdF3vWf5XEn/Euvs5IUtoI3YrexoaOEoglTHYoscNcIh78sIxRprVOHY1mrPr8Ccsh6PdOMBzgNBMMwNjoJqXodXn/XYuQIxrpT9ki4N0T)

- `(}.}:x)` Kill the c and r
- `` rplc a`,:`d,<'(,{.)' `` In what remains, replace `a` with enlist `,:` (another nesting level) and replace `d` with `(,{.)` (append first element)
- `".'y',~` Evaluate the resulting verb on the right arg `y`

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
f=->s,n{s[0]='';s<?r?s>?b?[0]+f[s,n]:[f[s,n]]:n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W165YJ6@6ONog1lZd3brYxr7IvtjOPskeKKCdFg2Ui7WKhtCxVnm1/8szMnNSFdJTS4q5FBSKdRTyFGwVVOL1igtyMksU1HUU1IHCBQogDQp5eiX58ZmxXKl5Kf@TE4t0FIy5klNSUkAsU67kxBQoBHJNgFwYAHKNAA)

Comment: Just for completeness, ruby port of xnor is only 33 `f=->s,*n{s[3]?f[s[1..-1],n,*n]:n}`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W165YRyuvujjaONY@Lbo42lBPT9cwVicPKBhrlVf7vzwjMydVIT21pJhLQaFYRyFPwVZBJV6vuCAns0RBXUdBHShcoADUCZTSK8mPz4zlSs1L@Z@cWKSjYMyVnJKSAmKZciUnpkAhkGsC5MIAkGsEAA "Ruby – Try It Online").  And in 2.7 (TIO is 2.5) you can do `s[1..]` for 31.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
Ｆ⮌η≡ιd≔⁺⟦⁰⟧θθa≔⟦θ⟧θＰ⭆¹θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYq9CsIwFEb3PsUl0w1UUMTFTj5AQXQMGS5pbAKhP7lpHcRnjykK8nH4hnOMo2hGCjk/xgh4s6uNbNFJCfz0yThAL@FVGWILohNnuDD7fsBrWBjVXtcwy43ml9A/UbP@mnfVLiH5Kfoh4T2V61ua8LBZ2eSs1LGGU4mF6agsCp13a/gA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⮌η≡ι
```

Loop over the `cdadadr` string in reverse and switch on each character.

```
d≔⁺⟦⁰⟧θθ
```

If it's a `d` then prepend a `0`.

```
a≔⟦θ⟧θ
```

If it's an `a` then wrap the value in a list.

```
Ｐ⭆¹θ
```

Stringify the final result. (For some reason, outputting using Charcoal's default output format produces a meaningless result.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
W;$L}¡ḢḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/cWsWn9tDChzsWAdH////N/ienJKYkFgEA)

Based on xnor's idea.

*-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan*

Comment: `W;$L}¡ḊḢ` saves one.